# Could be a web page displayed in telnet command line?

Tags: telnet

I remember one time i've tiped a web address in telnet with port 80 and seen a piece of html.

My question is:
What a page must have to be viewed in telnet command line.
I know that images couldn't be viewed, but the text could be?

Links to tutorials or guidelines are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you got the HTML you were viewing the page, right? If you want to view the *rendered version* of the page, then you need an application that can download HTML and render it. It's called a browser. ;-) For a plain text browser, check [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some text browsers around, e.g. [lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29) or [w3m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m)

Just install them on your server (every linux distri has packages for them) and use it in your command line, even over telnet or ssh.